# При загрузке из StringList в RichEdit выходит ошибка class EOutOfResources и line insertion error

Tags: delphi, строки, edit

Вот код, после которого выходит такая ошибка:

```
var
  i:string;
  sl2: TStringList;
begin
  re1.Clear;
  sl2 := TStringList.Create;
  sl2.LoadFromFile('0_doc.rtf');
  re1.Lines.AddStrings(sl2);
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так делать?

```
re1.Lines.LoadFromFile('0_doc.rtf');
```

загрузит файл правильно, с обработкой внутреннего форматирования.

В StringList же загрузятся сырые строки типа `{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1251\uc1\adeff0\de` и не факт, что они считаются правильно - как в StringList, так и при перебросе в РичЕдит.

Кроме того, в зависимости от версии RichEdt.dll размер текста в нём может быть ограничен (например, 64 КБ когда-то было).

Проверить лимит размера - EM_GETLIMITTEXT, но если не загружает маленькие файлы - дело не в размере.

Если нужна загрузка по частям для визуальных целей, можно создать невидимый RichEdit и копировать из него.

Можно также воспользоваться сообщением [EM_STREAMIN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamin). Вот какой-то [древний пример](http://delphimaster.net/view/1-1141208105) я делал

Comment: Я так загружаю, потому что хочу сделать загрузку частями в RichEdit из StringList. В Lazarus в RichMemo так работало, в BDS через StringList загружает только файлы из txt нормально, а именно rtf выдаёт такую ошибку. А насчёт ограничений памяти: 1. Где можно посмотреть его? 2. Даже rtf - файлы в несколько строк не загружает.

Comment: ТОгда задам более прямой вопрос: почему, например в RichMemo загружает строки из stringList RTF, а в RichEdit не загружает строки из StringList RTF

Comment: Про RichMemo я ничего сказать не могу.